# Imported Sass file can't find font file

Tags: sass, gatsby

I'm using gatsby-plugin-sass to include my sass files. I have a `web-animations.sass` file that imports `_typography.sass`. My `_typography.sass` has a font-face declaration like this:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'BrandonPrinted'
  src: url(../../global/fonts/brandonprinted-one-webfont.eot)
  src: url(../../global/fonts/brandonprinted-one-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(../../global/fonts/brandonprinted-one-webfont.woff) format('woff'), url(/src/page-assets/global/fonts/brandonprinted-one-webfont.ttf) format('truetype')
```

When I run `gatsby develop` I get this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                          19:51:15

These relative modules were not found:

* ../../global/fonts/brandonprinted-one-webfont.eot in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader?{"plugins":[]}!./src/page-assets/work-ive-done/subpages/web-animations/styles/web-animations.sass
* ../../global/fonts/brandonprinted-one-webfont.woff in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader?{"plugins":[]}!./src/page-assets/work-ive-done/subpages/web-animations/styles/web-animations.sass
```

It seems that the font url path is interpreted to be relative to `web-animations.sass`instead of relative to `_typography.sass` because if I move `web-animations.sass` up two levels, then this error goes away.

Is there a way to have `_typography.sass` look for the font files relative to its own location?

Comment: url is interpreted to be relative to your web root.

Comment: Is gatsby using webpack to build your module?

Comment: Yes, Gatsby uses webpack.

Comment: I am guessing your entry point is in ./src/page-assets, is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure... here's the Git repo for the plugin: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-sass
I've looked through it, but nothing jumps out at me yet.

Comment: Ok, it looks like there's a problem with `sass-loader` that Webpack uses not being able to resolve relative paths https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url. I'll see if I can alter Gatsby's Webpack config

Comment: Any resolution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I think the thing that worked for me was using `resolve-url-loader`... I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is resolved, but in case anyone runs across this in the future and wants an alternative solution [I answered a similar question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053550/379841) and included a repo with a deployed site demonstrating different ways of using static files with Sass.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by including the [resolve-url-loader Webpack loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader).

Here's my `gatsby-node.js` file:

```js
"use strict";

var ExtractTextPlugin = require(`extract-text-webpack-plugin`);

var _require = require(`gatsby-1-config-css-modules`),
    cssModulesConfig = _require.cssModulesConfig;

exports.modifyWebpackConfig = function (_ref, options) {
    var config = _ref.config,
        stage = _ref.stage;

    var sassFiles = /\.s[ac]ss$/;
    var sassModulesFiles = /\.module\.s[ac]ss$/;
    options['sourceMap'] = 'sourceMap';
    var sassLoader = `sass?${JSON.stringify(options)}`;

    switch (stage) {
        case `develop`:
        {
            config.loader(`sass`, {
                test: sassFiles,
                exclude: sassModulesFiles,
                loaders: [`style`, `css`, 'resolve-url-loader', sassLoader]
            });
            return config;
        }
        case `build-css`:
        {
            config.loader(`sass`, {
                test: sassFiles,
                exclude: sassModulesFiles,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([`css?minimize`, 'resolve-url-loader', sassLoader])
            });

            config.loader(`sassModules`, {
                test: sassModulesFiles,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(`style`, [cssModulesConfig(stage), 'resolve-url-loader', sassLoader])
            });
            return config;
        }
        case `develop-html`:
        case `build-html`:
        case `build-javascript`:
        {
            config.loader(`sass`, {
                test: sassFiles,
                exclude: sassModulesFiles,
                loader: `null`
            });

            config.loader(`sassModules`, {
                test: sassModulesFiles,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(`style`, [cssModulesConfig(stage), 'resolve-url-loader', sassLoader])
            });
            return config;
        }
        default:
        {
            return config;
        }
    }
};
```