# Gatsby/React SASS Background-Image

Tags: reactjs, sass, gatsby

How to specify background image in global SASS stylesheet? Within the "src" folder I have a "sass" folder contain a stylesheet with the following:

```
background-image: url(../assets/test.jpg)
```

The "assets" folder is on the same level as the "sass" folder. I addition to the path above, I have also attempted using "./" and "../../" to no avail.

**Error:**

`ERROR in ./src/assets/test.jpg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Calling `import image from '../assets/test.jpg'` alone, without calling the file from within SASS also throws the error.

---

I believe I've discovered the cause of the problem; my `include:` value is not properly configured. Currently, I have all of my media files located within this `/assets/` folder, and so it seems they are all being compiled as `.svg` files.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-react-svg`,
  options: {
    rule: {
      include: /assets/
    }
  }
}
```

Plugin issue is addressed at the bottom of its documentation.
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/?=gatsby-plugin-react-svg

---

Solved by renaming svg files and updating plugin settings `include: /\.inline\.svg$/`.

Comment: Do you have loader to handle .jpg  from sass  in your webpack.config.js ?

Comment: @Pio I receive the same error when calling directly from the js file. See update.

Comment: I had the same problem when I was importing a font file. (Unexpected character '�') So it looks a little strange. Show us your webpack.cofnig.js.
And double check that you load good file

Comment: Hi there, do you happen to have modified webpack setting in `gatsby-node.js` or use any plugins that might have done so?

Comment: @DerekNguyen List of plugins added. From my understanding, Gatsby comes configured with Webpack out the box to handle assets such as jpg, gif, svg, etc. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/importing-assets-into-files/#importing-assets-with-webpack

Comment: Where is your entry sass file?

Comment: @ksav Sass file is within a sass folder. `import '../sass/style.sass'`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
While the below solution does work, it is not ideal for the reasons described in the [Importing Assets Directly Into Files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/importing-assets-into-files/) and [Using the Static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder) docs pages.

Importing assets directly has these benefits for image and font files:

> - Missing files cause compilation errors instead of 404 errors for your    users.
> - Result filenames include content hashes so you don’t need to    worry about browsers caching their old versions.

After OP added update about `gatsby-plugin-react-svg` misconfiguration causing the issue I went back and tried using an `assets` folder in `src` instead of `static` at the root level and everything works fine.

**Original answer:**

In the [Importing Assets Directly Into Files docs page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/importing-assets-into-files/) you link to in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032810/gatsby-react-sass-background-image#comment98735268_56032810) it says up top:

> There are two major ways to import assets, such as images, fonts, and files, into a Gatsby site. The default path is to import the file directly into a Gatsby template, page, or component. The alternative path, which makes sense for some edge cases, is to use the [static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder).
>
> You can create a folder named static at the root of your project. Every file you put into that folder will be copied into the public folder. E.g. if you add a file named sun.jpg to the static folder, it’ll be copied to public/sun.jpg

You can then refer to it in your stylesheet like so:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(/puppy.jpg);
}
```

All that said, there is another [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189592/imported-sass-file-cant-find-font-file) where the OP answers their own question with a much more complicated solution, but if I were to answer that one I would suggest they move the fonts folder into the Static folder and follow a similar approach to the one outlined above.