# Gatsby how to import svg as background in scss correctly?

Tags: css, svg, gatsby

I'm getting error message `Can't resolve '../../images/hero.svg'` while

1. I'm trying to import svg image from `images folder`
2. and set it in `header.scss` as a background image:    `background-image: url('../../images/hero.svg');`

My gatsby structure:

```
├─ src
├── scss
│   ├── main.scss
│   ├── modules
│   └──── header.scss
└── images
    └── hero.svg
```

gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Test',
    description: 'test',
    author: '@gatsbyjs'
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`
      }
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        name: 'Test',
        short_name: 'test',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#663399',
        theme_color: '#663399',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/android-chrome-192x192.png'
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
      options: {
        rule: {
          include: /\.inline\.svg$/
        }
      }
    }
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't your question similar to the SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032810/gatsby-react-sass-background-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by creating `static` folder and placing svg file inside of it. Needed to also update path in scss file to `'/hero.svg'`

Comment: I can't believe it took me installing 2 Gatsby plugins and digging into the insides of Gatsby to find this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me I needed to import the svg in the React component (```import svgImport from '../../your/path';```, and add ```style={{backgroundImage: `url(${svgImport})`}}``` to the html element

Answer (score -2):

import heroSvg from '/hero.svg';

In the css, scss or css in js etc

```
 background-image: url(${heroSvg});
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
```